# Caching and crsftoken

Tags: django, caching

A view could be completely cached forever except the crsftoken, which obviously should not be cached. Is it possible to disable caching just for it or how is the common way of implementing this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308899/django-caching-causes-csrf-violations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Are you using Django's caching middleware? As per the docs, it looks like Django may handle it on its own: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#caching

If that doesn't work with your setup:

You might be able to solve this by loading the CSRF token in via Ajax on form submit.

I'd imagine it looking something like this:

some_template.html:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

your_form.html:

```
<form id="myForm">
     // form stuff
     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

some_javascript.js

```
// jQuery trigger warning
$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     $('#myForm').load('some_template.html');
     // unbind and submit
});
```

Comment: I am using the per view caching but the reference also covers this.